# Trying to test retrieval of file by mocking pipe function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pipe, supertest

The `db` object comes from the [cloudant](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cloudant) module.

This is the code I'm trying to test:

```
res.set('some-header', 'some-value');
res.status(200);

db.attachment.get('some-uuid', 'file').
  on('error', function(e) {
     console.log('err');
     reject(e);
  }).
  pipe(base64.decode()).pipe(_res).on('error', function(e) {
     console.log('err2');
     reject(e);
  });

fulfill(null);
```

Trying to mock the code above:

```
var sinon = require('sinon');
var request = require('supertest');

var attachment_1 = {
  get: sinon.stub(),
};
var db = {
  attachment: attachment_1
};

var obj = {};
var obj2 = {};
var sample = {};
obj.pipe = function(encoderfunction) {
  console.log('obj.pipe for encoding');
  return obj2;
};
obj2.pipe = function(res) {
  console.log('obj2.pipe');
  console.log(typeof res); // object
  return this;
};
obj2.on = function() {
  console.log('obj2');
};
sample.on = function() {
  console.log('sample.on');
  return obj;
};

db.attachment.get.withArgs('some-uuid', 'file').returns(sample);
```

This is the actual test:

```
it('should respond with file contents and status of 200', function(done) {
    request(app).get('/file/index.html')
      .expect(200)
      .end(function(err, res){
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
        console.log('res: ' + res);
        done();
    });
});
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
  1) should respond with file contents and status of 200:
     Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.
```

Comment: Isn't enough to do `.expect(200, done);` ?

Answer (score 0):

From the `supertest` docs:

> If you are using the .end() method .expect() assertions that fail will
>   not throw - they will return the assertion as an error to the .end()
>   callback. In order to fail the test case, you will need to rethrow or
>   pass err to done(), as follows:

```
describe('GET /users', function() {
  it('respond with json', function(done) {
    request(app)
      .get('/users')
      .set('Accept', 'application/json')
      .expect(200)
      .end(function(err, res) {
        if (err) return done(err);
        done();
      });
  });
});
```